# redis connection inside infinite loop

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

I'm creating a redis connection using phpredis client

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->pconnect(loclahost, 6336, 2) ;
$redis->select(15);
```

Now I used the $redis object inside an infinite loop.

```
while(true){
   ///using redis connection object.
}
```

Around 54 such individual processes were running but once or twice in a day I get an error like "read error on connection".

Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Why not issue a `PING` at the beginning of your loop, and if it fails, reconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think something like this would work.  **NOTE** I have not tested this, and I have not written PHP in a pretty long time.

```
function redisConnection() {
    try {
        $redis = new Redis()
        $redis->pconnect(localhost, 6336, 2);
        $redis->select(15);
        $redis->ping();
        return $redis;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new Exception("Can not connect: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

$redis = redisConnection();
while (true) {
    try {
        $redis->ping();
    } catch {
        $redis = redisConnection();
    }
    // Rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will test this. is this okay to use ping command every time inside infinite loop? will it affect performance?

Comment: It's about the simplest command you can execute.  How many cycles per second is this thing running?

Comment: Actually each processes used for sending SMS for different areas, I have to check few policy like same number can not more than one SMS per day and similar other policies that is I am managing through Redis.
each pick data from DB and send SMS after policy check.